# push into new array based on id - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to create new array based on the two different arrays with same id in Typescript/JavaScript?

```
let array1 = [
{
invoiceId: 1,
name:'Ajay',
contact:'0001'
},
{
invoiceId: 2,
name:'vijay',
contact:'1234'
},
{
invoiceId: 3,
name:'Amit',
contact:'4581'
},
];

let array2 = [
{
invoiceId: 1,
age:24,
email:'1223@gmail.com'
},
{
invoiceId: 2,
age:23,
email:'23gmail@gmail.com'
},
];
```

in both array the common field is invoice id based on invoiceid have to create new array as example give below.

```
let expectedresult = [
{
name:'Ajay',
age:24
},
{
name:'vijay',
age:23
},
{
name:'Amit',
age:null
},
];
```

how to handle this in Typescript/JavaScript. is there any solution based on Lodash?

Comment: Please remove the `reactjs` tag if the question has nothing to do with _ReactJS_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object map from array2 based on `invoiceId` as its key and then easily access it while iterating over array1.

```
const map2 = Object.fromEntries(array2.map(item=>[item['invoiceId'], item.age]))
const expectedArray = array1.map(item=> {
return {
name: item.name,
age: map2[item.invoiceId] ? map2[item.invoiceId] : null
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be one solution.

```js
   let array1 = [
        {
        invoiceId: 1,
        name:'Ajay',
        contact:'0001'
        },
        {
        invoiceId: 2,
        name:'vijay',
        contact:'1234'
        },
        {
        invoiceId: 3,
        name:'Amit',
        contact:'4581'
        },
    ];

    let array2 = [
        {
        invoiceId: 1,
        age:24,
        email:'1223@gmail.com'
        },
        {
        invoiceId: 2,
        age:23,
        email:'23gmail@gmail.com'
        },
    ];
    console.log(array1.map(item=>({name:item.name, age: array2.filter(filteritem=>filteritem.invoiceId===item.invoiceId)[0]?.age || null})))
```

Comment: As per the question, You should short circuit  the age to be `null`, instead of `undefined`. Use `filteritem.invoiceId===item.invoiceId)[0]?.age || null`

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map through `array1` and find the match in `array2`. Then return name & age if found.

```
let expectedresult = array1.map(el => {
  let match = array2.find(obj => obj.invoiceId === el.invoiceId)
  return {
    name: el.name,
    age: match ? match.age : null
  }
})
```